# Python 3.4.3 - Multiple item append and list extension

Tags: python, list, append

This is a pretty simple code so i don't feel like there is a need to say what
everything does.

```
four = []
for a in range(0,10):
    four = ['0','0','0','0']
    del four[:]
    four.append(a) 
    four.append(a)
    four.append(a)
    four.append(a)
    print(four)
```

> The output of the code is:

```
>>>['1','1','1','1']
>>>['2','2','2','2']
>>>['3','3','3','3']
>>>...
>>>['9','9','9','9']
```

My first question is, is there a way i could append the variable `a` to the list `four` all at once? So instead of having four lines of `four.append(a)`, i would have one or two lines that would also do the job.

Second, i want the list `four` to keep increasing in length by 1 every iteration.

So the output would be:

```
>>>['1','1','1','1']
>>>['2','2','2','2','2']
>>>['3','3','3','3','3','3']
>>>...
>>>['9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9']
```

Thank you for any answers. I know the solution is pretty simple but i just cannot figure out how to do it.

p.s. I strongly suspect that the answer to the first question is also the solution to the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# first
for i in range(0, 10):
    print([i for _ in range(4)])

# second
for i in range(0, 10):
    print([i for _ in range(4+i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add multiple values to a list is by using the `extend`
for example:

```
L = [1, 2]
>>> L.extend((3, 4, 5))
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```